# Recently updated to Aurora Serverless v2 from v1. RDS Bill increased 3x. How can I downgrade back to v1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

Our RDS Bill increased 3x after migrating from Aurora Serverless v1 to v2.

We can't figure out why - trying to find a way to downgrade back to v1.

Ideally, a slight cost increase only - but it looks like it 3x'd in price.

Comment: You should be able to look at your bill and see exactly why. Did you compare pricing of v1 to v2? What were your ACU settings on the v1 cluster, and what are the ACU settings on the v2 cluster?

Comment: You can't downgrade. You have to manually migrate all your data to new aurora dB.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Aurora Serveless V2 has a minimum ACU to 0.5, whereas V1 is 0, i.e., with V1 you are being charged when the database is paused/sleeping.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.upgrade.html#aurora-serverless.comparison-scaling

Essentially, Aurora V2 is not exactly serverless anymore.. There is always a resource (or half a resource) running. The capacity units for V2 are double the price compared to V1, so it might make sense to re-think the configuration (not sure how this affects the performance though).

As already mentioned, you can check the bill analysis to identify what is causing the extra costs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33476143)